# medium-zoom implementation is not working in Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to implement medium-zoom from https://www.npmjs.com/package/medium-zoom

These are the steps I followed

1. `ng new medium_zoom_test` (Angular 13) with routing & css
2. `npm install medium-zoom`
3. image is kept in assets

app.component.html

```
<h1>Zoom test</h1>
<img class="zoomy" width="50%" src="assets/image.svg">
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import mediumZoom from 'medium-zoom';

mediumZoom('.zoomy', {
  margin: 40,
  background: '#ffffff',
  scrollOffset: 40
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'medium_zoom_test';
}
```

On serving the application the webpage with image is visible. However, there's no zoom icon on hover and the image won't zoom on click. It's just a normal webpage with no change.

Any alternatives to implement the zooming of images are welcome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `mediumZoom` will work when the passed selector has no corresponding element in the DOM. What I mean is where you call `mediumZoom` function the component is not attached to the DOM yet. If you want to guarantee that you need to call it on `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook. Or you can do better which is to define a directive that applies the zoom affect like this :

```
import mediumZoom from 'medium-zoom';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appZoomie]'
})
export class ZoomieDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    mediumZoom(el.nativeElement, {
      margin: 40,
      background: '#ffffff',
      scrollOffset: 40
    })
   }
}
```

And use it like this :

```
<img appZoomie src=".."/>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-template-um3ff6?file=src/app/shared/zoomie.directive.ts)

Comment: Hi, that worked, appreciate your help :)